# Gain write access on multiuser SMB share with credentials of different user via cifscreds

Tags: samba, cifs, smbclient

I have a SMB share with 2 users (which are identical on both server and client): 1 is in the write list, 1 can only read. The share is mounted as multiuser with the credentials of the write-user. I'm able to authenticate and gain the correct access mode for both users, when I login to their accounts and use `cifscreds add server1` with their own credentials.

**Is it also possible for the readonly user to gain write access, by using the other users credentials (who can write on the share) with `cifscreds`? And if yes: How does it have to be done?**

For example the following situation:
There are the 2 users `brian` and `stewie` on both systems. `server1` exposes an SMB share, where `brian` is mentioned in the `write list`, but not `stewie`. The directory of the share is owned by a group, where both `brian` and `stewie` are members, and it has `2755` as file permissions. On `desktop1` the share is mounted with the `multiuser` option and `brian`'s credentials via the fstab. `stewie` can get his readonly access, by using `cifscreds add server1` and his password. If he can obtain `brian`'s credentials, is it possible for him to gain write access by using `cifscreds add -u brian server1` with `brian`'s password?

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve.  My Administrator senses are warming me something isn’t right.

Comment: This isn't for productive use. I'm learning for a Redhat certification, where one part is to create and mount a multiuser SMB share and test the permissions. Since the credentials from `cifscreds` are used to authenticate against the share, I wondered, if it is possible to go this way, or if it maybe is not possible for good reasons, that I don't know. If it is possible, then I would like to know how, so that I am able to configure this, if the task demands it.